# In PostgreSQL, how to add a list to an existing JSON object, using JSONB

Tags: json, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

This code:

```
do
$j$
declare arr text[]; i int; num text; obj jsonb; jb_arr jsonb[];

begin

        jb_arr = array_append(jb_arr, jsonb_build_object('k', 'acg', 'v', 'val'));
        jb_arr = array_append(jb_arr, jsonb_build_object('k', 'xyz', 'v', 'xxx'));

        obj = (select '{ "cmds":[]}'::jsonb);

        RAISE NOTICE '%', to_jsonb(jb_arr); 

        RAISE NOTICE '%', obj;

end;
$j$
```

Outputs this:

```
[{"k": "acg", "v": "val"}, {"k": "xyz", "v": "xxx"}]
{"cmds": []}
```

How do I merge those two so that I end up with this:

```
{"cmds": [{"k": "acg", "v": "val"}, {"k": "xyz", "v": "xxx"}]}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is how: (select json_build_object('cmds', jb_arr));